# How to create reverse dns lookup zone for Premium HDInsight?

Tags: azure, hadoop, azure-hdinsight, reverse-dns, apache-ranger

I have created a DNS zone in the azure. For example, for the IP range 192.0.2.128/26,I have created 128-26.2.0.192.in-addr.arpa. Now how should I create PTR records for Hdinsight vm's to be created ?

Answer (score -1):

When creating a reverse zone to host records for hosts with IPs that are in the 192.0.2.128/26 prefix, the zone name would be created by isolating the network prefix of the address (192.0.2) and then reversing the order (2.0.192) and adding the suffix **.in-addr.arpa**.

[image]

Comment: 2.0.192.in-addr.arpa would be the zone name, how can I create the PTR records for HDInsight cluster nodes that are gonna be created ?

Comment: @Vineesha.C

Microsoft have added the capability to create reverse DNS entries as well. So, you don’t need to create explicitly. Could you please check the permissions of domain user, who will be the admin on the account? Domain user admin should have permissions to 
• Permissions to create service principal objects and machine objects within the organizational unit
• Permissions to join machines to the Azure AD domain

Comment: I've checked the permissions, my domain user has admin rights and I did add a server to AD DS using that user.

Comment: I'm able to create the premium cluster. Thanks for the support!

Comment: @Vineesha.C  Glad to hear that your issue has been resolved.